# Proof that $a^\frac{1}{m} < a^\frac{1}{n} $ with $m < n, 0 < a < 1$ and $n,m \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: analysis, inequality

I've stumbled across the following inequality and have failed trying to prove it.

Sadly I were not able to find a solution - neither on this site, nor on mathematical search-engines.

$a^\frac{1}{m} < a^\frac{1}{n} $ with $m < n, 0 < a < 1$  **and**  $n,m \in \mathbb{N} $

I'm grateful for any kind of help & hints.

Comment: @Max0815 it's m < n, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rise both side of the inequality to the power $m\cdot n$ to find $a^n<a^m$ that is true since so since $n>m$
$$
a^n=a^m\cdot a^{n-m}<a^m
$$
because $a^{n-m}<1$ .

Answer (score 1):

Set $b:=a^{1/m}$, and $B:=a^{1/n}$, where $0<a<1$, and $n>m$.

By definition: $b^m=B^n=a<1;$

This implies $0< b, B <1.$

$B^n= B^m B^{n-m} =b^m;$

Since $B^{n-m} <1$ it follows that $B^m>b^m$, or

$(B/b)^m>1$, which implies $B/b>1.$